# set variable amount of hotkey listeners pynput

Tags: python, pynput

I would like to create a script that detects a variable amount of different hotkeys.
For example, say that I want three listeners on the hotkeys `<ctrl>+1`, `<ctrl>+2`, `<ctrl>+3`. I tried this:

```
from pynput import keyboard


def on_macro(key):
   print('You pressed <ctrl> '+key)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   for c in range(3):
      hotkey = keyboard.HotKey(
        keyboard.HotKey.parse('<ctrl>+'+str(c)),
        lambda: on_macro(c)
      )
      listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=hotkey.press, on_release=hotkey.release)
      listener.start()
```

My goal would be to have the same callback (`on_macro`) for every hotkey, and then inside of it determine which hotkey has been pressed and act consequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that whenever I press *ctrl* together with another key, the output of printing the *key* argument of *on_macro(key)* is in hexadecimal, but the problem is that pynput uses no standard hexadecimal values. In this case the "*ctrl + a*" is translated into "*\x01*", "*ctrl + b*" into "*\x02*" and so on.
Here is what you can do

```
import pynput

def on_macro(key):
    key = str(key)
    key = key.replace("'", '')
    # print(key) use this to discover which key has which value

    if key == '\\x01': # key == ctrl + a
        do_your_stuff()
    elif key == '\\x02': # key == ctrl + b
        do_other_stuff()

with pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_macro) as l:
    l.join()
```

to discover which key pressed with *ctrl* has which value, just print the *key* argument of your *on_macro(key)* function.
Hope this helped you

Comment: wow, this really is awkward. basically every hotkey has to be mapped beforehand and then you can use it... wish things were definetly less complicated

Comment: well... if it was easy everyone would be a programmer

Comment: no, that's not the case: we have standards, protocols, conveniences, abstractions we attend to. having a well-known and largely used library that doesn't follow such standards and forces a programmer to debug himself such a thing is, to be fair, very awkward.